# How to subset a single column fataframe and get a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with only one column and rownames

```
 > head(UMIpCells_df, n=10)
                      UMIs
MB04_GATAACTGGCCT 4571.266
MB04_ACCCTGTCATTT 4534.992
MB04_GTAAGACGAATG 4793.417
MB04_AGGCTATTCCAA 4786.393
MB04_ATTATCTGATTT 4478.233
MB04_CCCGGGTCTGCC 4765.347
MB04_AAACGAGCTGAC 4571.253
MB04_TGTTGCTTTTCG 4167.119
MB04_ACGTCCCCCAAA 4778.961
MB04_GTCGCGCAGTTC 4664.638
```

I want to subset the firs 5 rows but I got a numeric vector:

```
> UMIpCells_df[1:5,]
[1] 4571.266 4534.992 4793.417 4786.393 4478.233
```

However if I add an extra column to the UMIpCell_df the subset returns a df.
I found out that to return a df from a single column dataframe I have to add:
 drop = False

```
> UMIpCells_df[(1:5), ,drop=FALSE]
                      UMIs
MB04_GATAACTGGCCT 4571.266
MB04_ACCCTGTCATTT 4534.992
MB04_GTAAGACGAATG 4793.417
MB04_AGGCTATTCCAA 4786.393
MB04_ATTATCTGATTT 4478.233
```

However I found this odd and as basic as it is I will like to learn why subsetting the simplest df (only 1 column) has to be different that subsetting any other DataFrame (>1 column). Hope you do not get offended by the elementary of this question.

Comment: You're essentially asking "why did the language designers choose this default?". Language design can be pretty opinionated, so it's tough to answer this definitively. Most people agree that it is at best a problematic design decision at this point, but changing it now would create too much disruption. If you run into Ihaka or Gentlman personally you could I suppose ask them.

Comment: Is correct behavior this, the reason you take the single column is to get a vector, otherwise you’ll get more columns if you want to operate with the df, if here comes in place that you need a label of this column than that one can added so your question or frustration is not the case here, get more columns and you’ll get the dataframe format or you can just point/reference the column from dataframe if you want to plot or do calculations. Voting to be closed because is not a issue with the code or behavior.

Comment: Dear sb0709, I appreciate the help. However I do not feel confortable with your answer. Firstly you responded:  "so your question or frustration is not the case here". Honestly , you shouldn't be guessing the mood of someone that post a question. I was not frustrated but afraid of missing something basic and important.  Secondly ,"question have not place here":  Are you  saying that  stackoverflow is not a place for basic question. In that case, can you tell the standards in place to evaluate if a post is advanced enough to be considered a useful post in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using tibbles and `data_frame` instead of the standard data.frame.   While not base R, packages such as `dplyr` help to "correct" some of these behaviors you noticed that may no longer be beneficial.

Check out the vignette on tibbles here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html

And here is a brief comparison of tibbles to data frames as well as some comparisons when subsetting:
http://r4ds.had.co.nz/introduction-2.html#tibbles

Answer (score 0):

`head(UMIpCells_df, n=5)` is also a data frame, so you can just do:

```
new.df <- head(UMIpCells_df, n=5)
```

Comment: Yes I know, but that was just a easy way to show my problem. I have >1000 rows that I was trying to subset with a character vector with colnames